# Redirect old permalinks with Month and name to Post name on new site

Tags: permalinks, redirect, 404-error

We migrated blog posts from an old WP site that was using Month and name permalink structure. The new site is using Post name permalink so anything with `YEAR/MO` format in url is not found in Webmaster tools.

Ultimately, we want anything not found that looks like this:

```
/2012/05/post-name/
```

to redirect to this:

```
/post-name
```

Is there a way to either write a redirect with wildcards that targets the year and month and redirects all to the Post name permalink? Or another plugin or technique we can use within WP? any other ideas or suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that the problem is not more simple, such as checking in your admin panel that you permalinks setup is the same as it was? Sounds to me like you had the permalinks set to /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/

Comment: Ya, we ended up just using same permalink structure. Wondering which is better for SEO though.

Answer (score 4):

[Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/research/permalink-helper.php) Redirect Creation tool will allow you to generates the code you need to manually add to your site's .htaccess file to redirect all the posts to the new /%postname%/ structure.

Enter your site URL, Your old permalink structure and click generate redirect on SEO tool website page. Add generated code to top of your .htaccess

Your Redirects Rule should be:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ YOUR-DOMAIN/$3
```